Я начал работать в Unity, но столкнулся с проблемой, что объект отображается в вкладке game, но не отображается в вкладке scene
помоги пожалуйста, в вкладке scene не отображается объект, но при этом во вкладке game он есть, как это исправить? Координаты объекта правильные, объект перед камерой

Поздравляю, ты изменил маску отображения соответствующего Layer в Scene. Scene.Layers.

попробуй кликнуть в иерархии на нужный тебе объект два раза ЛКМ и у тебя автоматически найдет твой объект
